# How to get Form Values from Javascript-added Checkboxes in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am adding checkboxes to a  by setting the innerHtml property as below.

```
function ShowCheckbox(uid) {
    document.getElementById("samplediv").innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' value='on' name='box_" + uid + "' id='box_" + uid + "'/> Some Text Here";
}
```

This is on a .aspx page

I am trying to retrieve the values of the dynamic checkboxes from the codebehind in c# but am not finding them being posted back.  I've read on the IE issue (pre-IE8) about it not handling the name attribute well however I'm in IE9 and apparently it's not a problem if you use the innerHtml approach rather than directly adding to the DOM.

I tried requesting values in codebehind via Request.Form and Request.Params with no luck either way.

Any idea why the dynamic checkboxes aren't getting posted back?

Comment: Are the checkboxes actually checked when you post the form?

Comment: Yes, they are checked visually from the browser.

Comment: Is this sampleDiv in your code snippet located between the `<form>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using **jQuery**. Appending element into DOM is quite easy and it works.

```
function ShowCheckbox(uid) {
    $("<input type='checkbox' value='on' name='box_" + uid + "' id='box_" + uid + "'/>")
   .appendTo($("#sample");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you do a form submit, all the data will be sent to the server. Then ASP.NET engine will try to create server-side "representation" of your HTML controls. It will try to match it's Controls collection with the data from the client, by using id's or names. So you need to create server-side inputs **before** page start map data and controls. In other words you need to make the page to find the same controls in Controls collection of the page on the server. So, I believe you need to do the control's creation on Page_Init or something...

Here is a good explanation of dynamic controls in ASP.NET: http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx